# Twincat 3 - SQL Server - How to make a select statement with unknown return values

Tags: sql, twincat

I need to make a select statement on a SQL database using twincat3. As far as I am able to understand, I need to define a array of a structure, that is then populated with the `FB_SQLResultEvt`.
The structure needs to be the same as the result I am expecting, (int, string and so on for each column of the returned values) and the array needs to be as big as the maximum number of rows I expect to get back.

Question is: How can I get a result from a database with any columns (like a select * from anytable) and that can have any number of rows? I cannot/dont want to declare a immense array for each select query that i have to run.